# two events happen on changePage

Tags: jquery, xcode, cordova, jquery-mobile, ios6

Imagine that i'm in the page `home.html`, there, i have a click event to a element that will fire a `changePage` to `user.html`

OK, the element in the `home.html` is setted in the `header`, and in the `user.html`, i have another element in the **same html position**.

The problem is: When i click in the element on `home.html`, my another `vclick` event in the other page happens to. This problem happen only using `vclick` or `tap`, using `click` **works** normal, and the two elements need to be in the **same html position** in both pages.

this is my event binded in the home.html

```
accessProfile: function(){
    $("body").on("vclick", ".accessUser", function(){
        $.mobile.changePage("user.html");
    });
}
```

and this one is binded to the user.html

```
accessHome: function(){
    $("body").on("vclick", ".accessHome", function(){
         $.mobile.changePage("home.html");
    });
}
```

this is just a example, so, `vclick` in the `accessUser` , then `changePage` happens, but when is finished, the event `.accessHome` happens and back to home. Again, this only happen when both element are in the same html position.

Comment: You have to specify which item should handle the event. Try replace $(`body`) with `$.mobile.activePage`. The event will be triggerd in the active page.

Comment: can you give a example, just to make sure the way i`m doing.

Comment: Hmmm.. I just noticed that the elements have different classes. Ok try this `$('.acessHome').on('vclick', function () { your code });`

Comment: Still not working, but this time, the event dont fire, as the content its not in the dom (ajax), i need to delegate the event, that why i`m  using `$("body").on("vclick", ".accessHome", function() {});`

Comment: @Ricardo: If it is not a problem, send me your pages and I will fix it for you. Cant tell much from this code examples.

Comment: @Gajotres forgot to tell, everything is happening with ios6, in the emulated divice and in the mobile divice to. Android didint try it.

Comment: Still if it is not a problem send me your pages. I do this for fun :) , jQuery Mobile error are numerous but they usually fall under few categories.

Comment: And tell me one other thing, do you use document ready to initialize this code or do you use standard jQuery Mobile page events?

Comment: @Gajotres i use document ready to all events, will try to execute this code in a little example, do you think that have something to do with doc ready ?

Comment: @Gajotres one more question, what is the best way of handle this? call a pageinit to each pageid or put several page id's bind to a single pageinit: something like `$(document).on("pageinit", "#page-home, #page-user, #page-settings", function(e,val){ if(e.target.id == "pageid") });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at the time, my problem was solved changeing everything to a `pageinit` instead of `$(document).ready(function(){...});` and preventing multiple events using:

```
 $("body").on("touchstart", ".someElement", function(event){
    if(event.handled !== true){ // This will prevent event triggering more then once
        // code
        event.handled = true;
    }
    return false;
 });
```